# How can you implement SignalR in a controller on a watcher event?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, signalr

I have a working project on which I have to add SignalR for real time push events but I don't know how to do it.

The events come from a watcher who's looking for new files and these files are read and the content is added to a database and then added onto the web page.
The content should appear on the page as it's created without having to refresh.

The current controller takes data from the database and sends it to the view which displays it.

I followed [this](https://www.mithunvp.com/asp-net-core-signalr-example-without-chat-demo/) to get going but I have no idea how to implement SignalR when the controller is a client.

**Here's my controller:**

```
public class PropertyController : Controller
{
    private readonly DataAccess data;

    public PropertyController(DataAccess data)
    {
        this.data = data;
    }


    public ActionResult ViewProperties()
    {
        /*
        * Puts the data that I want to show in result
        */

        //Do I have to write something here?

        return View(result);
    }
}
```

**Watcher:**

```
private readonly IHubContext<PropertyHub> _hubContext;

//FileWatcher constructor with the HubContext injection

private static void OnChanged(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        _hubContext //Don't know what to write here...
    }
```

I don't really understand how DI works in my case.

Comment: Your watcher should connect to the hub, and call a method to tell it that a new event has happened. The hub should then invoke a method on the relevant clients, passing along the event data (or at least telling them to perform a refresh). Most likely this will mean your controller shouldn't be a client at all. Instead, some JavaScript running in the user's browser would be a client.

Comment: I think you need to read the docs more, you're missing the fundamental understanding of what SignalR does and what MVC Controllers do. They're both used to talk to the client, not talk to different parts of your app. SignalR is for communicating in real time with a client, due to the bidirectional nature of the communication protocol. MVC is for responding to a client initiated HTTP request.

Comment: By following this tutorial I was able to get a simple client/server setup going where I `HTTP POST` messages to an endpoint which then get `push`ed to the client (in the browser): https://www.codemag.com/Article/1807061/Build-Real-time-Applications-with-ASP.NET-Core-SignalR

Comment: I'm really uncomfortable in javascript and I have no idea what to put in a js file to show data. For SignalR and everything else, I'm trying really hard to understand the docs but I have trouble with the technical stuff. I'll see if I can find something for the js. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can find information and examples about [Background tasks with hosted services in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio).

In the hosted service, write the same logic which you have found in the MyFileWatcher. Injecting the HubContext in order to send notification via SignalR.

[Dependency injection in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-2.2)

Do not need to write any logic in the controller for this purpose. But you still have to get an initial list of files and a controller is a good place for it.